# Why is mysql_config reporting the wrong socket file location?

Tags: mysql

The mysql_config program is reporting the socket file location as:

```
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But in /etc/my.cnf, the location is clearly stated as:

```
/tmp/mysql.sock
```

When I use "mysqladmin variables" to check the socket, it is reported correctly. Why is mysql_config incorrect, and how can I fix it?

Comment: According to its documentation, mysql_config is *not* supposed to show you the socket you've configured in my.cnf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using?

I use OSX and it very rarely uses default locations for, well, anything!

The '/tmp/mysql.sock' value is the default for my.cnf out of the box, as far as I am aware you should change your my.cnf to reflect your socket location in respect of your environment.

In MAMP (apache, mysql,php bundle for OSX) it is located in 'Applications/MAMPP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'

```
MAMP my.cnf [default]
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
#port       = 9999
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_config --socket`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-config.html#option_mysql_config_socket) shows "The *default* Unix socket file, defined *when configuring MySQL*" (i.e. at compile-time).